# How to change the map location from google map api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-api

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gmap3/5.0b/gmap3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Map Area -->
<div class="panel googleMaparea">
    <div id="googleMap"></div>
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4URMQ/)

In index.html, I am getting `Jakarta` as map location

Reference image:
[image]

I am using `gmap3.min` javascript api which is included in the project file.

I need to change the map location to some other location. How to achieve it?
Your help is highly appreciated.

Updated:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAr5h/)**

Comment: Maybe nobody want's to download a unknown zip, post the code.

Comment: Dr.Molle, see the uploaded project file..it contains html, images, css, js files..If I post it here..it wont be useful..

Comment: It wouldn't be useful for you, because you have to do something. For the users it would be helpful when they 1. Dont have to download something 2. Don't have to fetch the important stuff out of your project(this question doesn't need css and images to be answered) 3. follow a possible broken link in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the center position of Google Maps and marker using,

```
   $('#test').gmap3({
     map:{
        options:{
         center: [-33, 151],//place the latitude and longitude of map's center position
         zoom: 8
        }
     },
     marker:{
        latLng: [-33, 151],// place the latitude and longitude of the marker
        callback: function(){
         $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
     }
    });
```

See the [***documentation here***](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/5-getting-started/)

**Updated:**

[***See demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/MmbFM/)

Inside `index.html`, apply this towards the bottom before `</body>`

```
        <script>
   $('#googleMap').gmap3({
     map:{
        options:{
         center: [-33, 151],//place the latitude and longitude of map's center position
         zoom: 8
        }
     },
     marker:{
        latLng: [-33, 151],// place the latitude and longitude of the marker
        callback: function(){
         $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
     }
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: How can I change this in my code?

Comment: And, it is pointing to one location as per your code. But in my case, it is showing only the specific location

Comment: @user1745838 did you see the comments in my code? one is for setting the map center position center[x,y] change this to the location you like. And the other is marker for marking any specific regions in map.

Comment: @user1745838 See I have updated my answer with an example..http://jsfiddle.net/MmbFM/

Comment: @user1745838 Please update your code in your question. Otherwise your question will result in downvotes. Kindly put the code which you have worked on than putting the download link of your project files(remove it ).

Comment: I accepted the answer..but I cant able to change it in my code..:(

Comment: @user1745838 Just see my updated answer. Place that code towards the bottom of index.html before </body> tag.. and let me know.

Comment: Excellent and awesome Mr.newTag...really superb....Thanks a lotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt !!!!

Comment: How to remove that red border??

Comment: @user1745838  remove $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');

Comment: Really I am thankful for you Mr.newTag..Want your help in my forthcoming projects..Will you move this conversation to chat?